# MOSFET with Integrated Driver for Boost Converter

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, pic, boost

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFWJbS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Trying to build a boost converter using a PIC microcontroller with minimum number of external components. Was hoping to find an NMOS with integrated driver (dashed rectangle above) in a small surface mount package (e.g. SOT-23-5) to use as the switch and drive it directly from the PIC output pin. Searched for 'gate drivers' and 'power switches' but couldn't find any suitable part.

Edit:
This is a commonly used configuration (driver+MOS) and was under the impression that more devices in a single package would be available. Why are devices like this seemingly unobtainable?

Comment: From what I know so far, this question is off-topic as it is asking for recommendations which is an opinion based thing. Best thing to do is to go to somewhere like farnless, digikey etc and edit the search parameters so you can find something that suits your design to your specifications as every design is different and everyone has different requirements

Comment: Was trying to ask if there are such parts available/common and which category will they be listed in? Sorry if wording is not clear.

Comment: No worries! There will be such parts available

Comment: What are they called? How to search for them? Thanks

Comment: You just need to work out what you need from it and use that to change search parameters in the sites you buy them from

Comment: Just go to digikey or farnell or wherever, go to the page for mosfet and then you can change the search parameters to narrow it down to ones that meet your requirements

Comment: That's what I've been doing and can't find parts with integrated gate drivers.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. If you want everything inside that dashed rectangle, then you just need to buy yourself a boost regulator chip. Otherwise if you want to make one yourself, then you're gonna have to make your own gate driver circuit. Google how to make a boost regulator or something and see if that helps

Comment: OK thanks. Found the lack of parts surprising since driver+MOSFET is commonly needed. Cheers

Comment: @eymre this question has become closed because you are specifically saying you couldn't find a part that matches. Now, if you reword your question to something like "why are devices like this seemingly unobtainable", you might get the question re-opened and some more answers other than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to find an NMOS with integrated driver

No (bold statement!), I think this is a rare beast and there are a few reasons that spring to mind: -

- To properly turn on the MOSFET (without damage) you need a supply rail of a few volts (maybe 5 volts) to no more than 20 volts and this instantly restricts application usage of such a device.
- The low end supply voltage (if a tad too low) might indeed cause the MOSFET to fail because it doesn't turn on adequately enough so, an extra pin for under-voltage lock-out (UVLO) would likely be needed and, if you look at a lot of integrated switchers, these are quite common. Not turning on enough would generate too much heat in many applications and burn the MOSFET.
- The device would need to protect against a supply voltage greater than 20 volts else the gate source region could become damaged by over-voltage and, not surprisingly, many integrated switchers **do have** an internal linear voltage regulator and this usually means a Vcc pin to hang a power supply decoupler on. Can you see that you are beginning to adopt the fuller functionality of a proper integrated switcher?
- To drive the MOSFET in light load applications requires a peak drive current to the gate-source parasitic capacitance of a few mA i.e. just enough current to adequately activate the gate without wasting power. In higher load power applications this has to rise to several hundred mA to avoid switching losses being too great. Now, you need another pin that sets this current appropriately for the application.
- The majority of engineers that require a boost converter will not try and use a microprocessor as the "brain" because they recognize that trying to control duty cycle under varying load and input voltage scenarios is best left to an integrated switching device.

There may be other good reasons that people can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally use a "logic level FET" for this type of application. This class of FETs has been designed with a gate structure that allows them to be controlled directly from a logic level output. No additional gate driver is needed.

Comment: The logic level FETs that I've checked have too big of a gate charge (Qg) to be driven at 250kHz 5V 25mA. Basically the rise/fall times turn out to be too long and generate more heat than the FET can handle. Do you have any FETs in mind?